# Parsing tokens with regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regular expression that will allow me to parse a colon delimited token, formatted as a key and value pair.

```
[/foo:bar] // where [key:value]
```

The tricky part is that a token value can contain another token.

```
[/foo:[/foo:bar]]
```

In the above case, I want to match foo as the key and [/foo:bar] as the value. The following expression works:

```
^\[/([^:]+):(.*)\]+$
```

However, this does not work when the string has multiple tokens. For example:

```
[/foo:[/foo:bar]][/foo:bar] // results in foo and [/GetPath:[/GetPath:]]][/foo:bar
```

I imagine I'm only slightly off, but I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: Nested stuff is a very bad thing for RegEx to match. It's only really achievable through engine-specific special operators. For that reason, it is generally considered that wiring up your own quick parser is much more efficient than spending days on a single expression to attempt it.

Comment: Please check the famous [parsing HTML with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) for suggestions on parsing nested braces (seriously, just skip funny once)... On other hand finding sample for proper parsing of an XPath expressions may be better approach.

Comment: Regex'es are a mandatory part of every modern programmer's toolkit; so is being able to whip up a trivial parser. My advice is to abandon regex for this task, for which they are unsuitable, and practice your parser writing.

Comment: You can use [.NET regex balancing groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition) to count and solve such problems if you want to do it with regex.

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches name with a nested value:

```
\[/([^:]+):(.*?)\](?=\[|$)
```

The change was to add a look ahead that asserts the character following the delimiting right square bracket must be a new term or end of input.

As per this [live demo on rubular](http://rubular.com/r/lDwTSOw56y), when using input

```
[/foo:[/foo:bar]][/foo:bar]
```

The resulting matches are:

```
Match 1...
Group 1:    foo
Group 2:    [/foo:bar]
Match 2...
Group 1:    foo
Group 2:    bar
```